# how complicated can a match pattern be, trying to convert macro from termion to crossterm

Tags: rust

I have this code that works in termion

```
    macro_rules! key {
        (char $x:expr) => {
            Event::Key(Key::Char($x))
        };
        (ctrl $x:expr) => {
            Event::Key(Key::Ctrl($x))
        };
        ($x:ident) => {
            Event::Key(Key::$x)
        };
    }

pub fn handle_keypress_loading_mode<B: Backend>(evt: Event, app: &mut App<B>) {   
 match evt {
        key!(ctrl 'c') | key!(char 'q') => {
            app.prompt_exit();
        }
        key!(char 'l') | key!(Right) | key!(ctrl 'f') => {
            app.move_selected_right();
        }
```

the key! macro is nice short hand. The match code reads nicely (not my code, its from diskonaut). Evt is an enum

So for the first key! expansion we get

```
Event::Key(Key::Ctrl('c')) |....=>{
```

ie is this event an Event::Key specifically for the Ctrl + 'c'.

I cannot work out how to make it work with crossterm the same way.

Crossterms key events are slightly different. The key and its modifiers are separated. There is no simple literal for a key, so I need to generate

```
Event::Key(KeyEvent{code:KeyCode::Char('c'), modifier:CONTROL})
```

or

```
  Event::Key(KeyCode::Char('c').into()) // for plain c not ctrl c
```

or

```
  Event::Key(KeyEvent::new(KeyCode::Char('c'), modifier:CONTROL))
```

but none of these are acceptable patterns for match. I could, of course, recode the way that macro is used, but its used a lot, and it would be nice to minimize the changes throughout the code base.

I was wondering about building a table of key/mod values, but find that I cannot have a lookup in a pattern either.

I am stuck, any ideas? Maybe there is some match syntax I am not aware of.

Comment: The first one looks like a perfectly acceptable patterns. Patterns are constant, so you can't call functions in a pattern, but the first one looks OK to me. (You may need `KeyModifiers::CONTROL`, since [`CONTROL`](https://docs.rs/crossterm/0.17.7/crossterm/event/struct.KeyModifiers.html#associatedconstant.CONTROL) appears to be an associated constant, so you can't import it directly.) Could you show the error message you get for it, and show the code to reproduce the error?

Comment: @SvenMarnach oh my, that first one does work when not macroized - more investigation needed, BRB

Comment: @SvenMarnach i must have had an odd typo somewhere, ty for making me try again